Inputted data loses interactivity after the page reload
I am trying to save the data on local storage of the browser, the data is saved but after the reload of the webpage its CSS and JS interactivity are all lost. I have tried to recreate the HTML elements along with their associated event listeners in showTask() function, but it still didnt worked so i deleted that again.

Below is my code
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box");
const listContainer = document.getElementById("list-container");

function addTask() {
    if(inputBox.value === '') {
        alert("Write something!");
    }
    else {
        let li = document.createElement("li");           //creates element li
        li.textContent = inputBox.value;                //stores the value from inputbox in in the new created li
        listContainer.appendChild(li);                 // displays the li in list container (variable created at the start of the page)
        let remove = document.createElement("span");  
        remove.textContent = "\u00d7";                //this code is for the cross icon
        li.appendChild(remove);                       // appending the span which includes the remove icon in each li
    }
    inputBox.value = ""; //empties the input field after the text entered
    saveData();
}

//this event listener on clicking on li makes its class name checked or unchecked
//if clicked on the delete icon which is a span tag it removes it
listContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "LI") {
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
        saveData();
    }
    else if (e.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        saveData();
    }
}, false);

//saveData function stores the data in local storage of the browser
function saveData() {
    localStorage.setItem("data", listContainer.textContent);
}

function showTask() {
    listContainer.textContent = localStorage.getItem("data");
}

showTask();


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section class="to-do-section">
            <h2>To-Do List <img src="images/icon.png" alt="icon"></h2>
            <section class="input-section">
                <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Write your To-do's here!">
                <button onclick="addTask()">Add</button>
            </section>
            <ul id="list-container"> 
                <!-- <li class="checked">Task 1</li>
                <li>Task 2</li>
                <li>Task 3</li> -->
            </ul>
        </section>
    </main>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Try saving the innerHTML of listContainer instead of its textContent property value and let us know if it's any better. Thanks - and be aware not to post images of code instead of including in the post as formatted text

@traktor Thank you so much it worked! But i really didnt understood why it was not working with textContent because i was told that they work the same and textContent is better because it avoids the XSS injections. About the code image, i wanted to write all in formatted text but it was giving error that the code is more than details.

textContent is just the words within an element and its descendants, without any tag information about how it should be rendered and/or interacted with. On the other hand innerHTML contains HTML markup (tags) as well and when set on a container element,  recreates the same element structure in the DOM that the markup tags describe. Not sure about the error, have look at the "Code Blocks" section in the link in my earlier comment or search for "markdown code blocks" on the net.
